# Numpy N-D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an numpy array with size[128,128,128,3]. You can see this as a stack of 1 16 groups of 8-image stack of size 128x128x3. I want to reshape it to size[16,128,128,24]. 
The code I have is as follows:

```
b_imgs_96_reshape = np.empty([16,128,128,24])
for i in range(0,128):
    b_imgs_96_reshape[i//8,:,:,(i%8)*3:(i%8)*3+3] = b_imgs_96[i,:,:,:]
```

but I got the error and it crashes sometimes randomly. 
Here is the error message:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Can anyone help me out with this issue?? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is `b_imgs_96` a numpy array or a Python list?

Comment: Take a look at the `reshape` and `transpose` functions.  A combination of those is the typical way to do what it appears you're trying to do.

Comment: It is a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

If your input `b_imgs_96` has shape (128, 128, 128, 3) and a scalar dtype then

1) there are no lists in the snippet you posted that could possibly trigger the error you are reporting

2) memory should not be an issue here unless you are doing this on your smart watch; indeed 128x128x128x3x8 ~50MB for a 64bit dtype

You can and probably should avoid the loop, though, and instead do

```
 b_imgs_96_reshape = np.moveaxis(b_imgs_96.reshape(16, 8, 128, 128, 3), 1, 3).reshape(16, 128, 128, 24)
```

Comment: I used your code and it still randomly crashes with the message:            
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (128,128,3) into shape (128)

Comment: @JiajuOrangeYue Please copy'n'paste the exact output of `type(b_imgs_96)`, `b_imgs_96.shape` and `b_imgs_96.dtype`

Answer (score -1):

I can't reproduce your error.  This runs fine:

```
b_imgs_96 = np.ones([128,128,128,3])

b_imgs_96_reshape = np.empty([16,128,128,24])
for i in range(0,128):
    b_imgs_96_reshape[i//8,:,:,(i%8)*3:(i%8)*3+3] = b_imgs_96[i,:,:,:]
```

If it's intermittent I might suspect a memory issue.

Comment: It randomly crashes. I suspect a memory issue too. Is there anyway to free the memory which numpy occupied?

Comment: `del b_imgs_96` would delete the object and free the memory.